# jQuery addClass class that is already psuedo (:hover)

Tags: jquery, css, naming-conventions, pseudo-class

I wrote a javascript/jQuery solution to keep the :hover css on an Icon(element) after the mouse is moved away from it and on to a lightbox that hovering on the element triggers - I wanted to keep Icon stylized so you could see what activated the lightbox.

In the css I use:

```
#toolbar-content li:hover, .tt-li-text{
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.93);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #333333;
}
```

The `#toolbar-content li:hover` is for the original hover styling and the `.tt-li-text` is what I use in the jQuery addClass as shown below:

```
$("#toolbar-content li:nth-child("+mi+") i").removeClass("tt-li-text");
```

The complete code is:

```
function hvrOn(mi)
{   
// Select nth-child of menu array - e.g. passed by afterBoxStart: hvrOn(1)
$("#toolbar-content li:nth-child("+mi+")").addClass("tt-li"); //div
$("#toolbar-content li:nth-child("+mi+") i").addClass("tt-li-text"); //icon
 return true;
}
function hvrOff(mi)
{
// Select nth-child of menu array - e.g. passed by afterBoxEnd: hvrOff(1) 
$("#toolbar-content li:nth-child("+mi+")").removeClass("tt-li");
$("#toolbar-content li:nth-child("+mi+") i").removeClass("tt-li-text");
return true;
}
```

My question is whether it's possible to somehow reuse the original css classname `#toolbar-content li:hover` in the addClass or should it just be the way I'm doing it now - using a second name without :hover?

Comment: 1) Java is NOT Javascript. 2) `:hover` is a pseudo-class, you can't set it via JS/jQuery. What you can do is add an `.active` class on hover, and not remove it on hover out, so the active color remains.

Comment: Jeremy Thille is right about the :hover pseudo-class. You'll need to listen to events and add a class on hover while not removing it when you move out. I've recently answered another question that uses this concept: [How to Make a Menu Like Stack Overflow's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28921276/511529)

Comment: @Jeremy @ GolezTrol- I have a working solution. My question was about the classNames. I'm sure you can't use a className that contains :hover in addClass / removeClass but wanted to check here to make sure. It would have saved having to double up on classNames as I doing now.